# How to achieve the LongListSelector jump list in a wp8.1 windows runtime app

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to get this feature in a wp8.1 Windows Runtime app?

[image: jump list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Shawn Kendrot wrote a blog post about it.

[Migrating from the LongListSelector to the ListView in Windows Phone XAML Apps](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx)

It comes down to:

- Use a ListView for vertical item list
- Define a GroupStyle instead of using GroupHeaderTemplate
- Use SemanticZoom to display the jump list
- Use GridView to add header items horizontally to jump list

The point is to use the new controls - [ListView, GridView](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd) and [SemanticZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.semanticzoom.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the `SemanticZoom` control as described in [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/07/01/gridview-and-listview-controls.aspx):

> Jump Lists
>   Finally, I'll show how to replicate the jump-list style unique to Windows Phone. This allows a user to tap on a group header, see a summary view of the groups and then jump to the point in the list he's after. This is different in Windows Phone 8.1 than in Windows Phone 8.0, which used an alternate jump layout with the LongListSelector. Instead, it's done with a SemanticZoom control, and defining zoomed in and zoomed out views. In the example in Listing 3, the zoomed-in view will be the ListView just created. I'll also define a second ListView, which will only display the group headings.

```
<SemanticZoom>
  <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}"
      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}">
      <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
      </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
  </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
  <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    <ListView
      ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group.Property1}" 
                      Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

...

Comment: Hi Filip,
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}". 
In this What is Grouped Data? and in the above mentioned Code I beleive ZoominView as Header item and ZoomoutView as List of items.

Comment: I ahce some issue in normal list view in grouping as well . Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816721/longlistselector-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 1):

I have reimplemented a native looking `LongListSelector` control using the `SemanticZoom` control.

Have a look at this page: https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LongListSelector

[image]
[image]