# Show Contact List like whatsapp does [Windows Phone 8.1]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, whatsapp

Whatsapp application for Windows Phone 8.1 is a Silverlight App.

Thing is I would like to know how did they list the entire Contact List in the "ALL Contacts" tab.
Its too fast to fetch the entire data programmatically, so i am assuming they are using a contact picker to do this. The favorite tab is a private contact store I guess but thats normal.

But it is possible to *put* a contact picker object inside a xaml page? Like putting my header and some buttons then the ContactPicker?

Comment: I don't know whether they load the contact list in a background task or in the app itself, but they pull the contact list periodically and store it locally and/or send it to their servers. I think so, because it doesn't update immediately when you add a new contact. Some code on how to do this, can you find here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Contacts-Integration.aspx.

Comment: WhatsApp caches data internally and updates it when you run the app. Other than that, it appears to be a regular jump list.

Answer (score 0):

[How to achieve the LongListSelector jump list in a wp8.1 windows runtime app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814995/how-to-achieve-the-longlistselector-jump-list-in-a-wp8-1-windows-runtime-app)

Jumplists im afraid. In Silverlights contacts access is pretty fast but in XAML apps its a little bit slower (much more slower) so i was thinking in a way to make it work on XAML.

@sibbl:
Jumplists and your posts combined its a good way.