# LongListSelector Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I wanted to Develop a similar layout like Longlist Selector Wp8 in Windows phone 8.1.

I came across a issue, my list is not appearing.

XAML page

```
<Grid >

    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="MainGrps"
                      IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainGrps}}"  Margin="50">

         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid Background="Gray">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding ItmName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding ItmType}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" >
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid Background="Red">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GrpItmName}" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsCount}" Foreground="White"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lst_grp = new List<Grp>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Grp grp = new Grp();
            grp.GrpItmName = "grp name " + i;
            grp.ItemsCount = i;

            grp.LstItms = new List<Itm>();

            Itm itm = new Itm();
            itm.ItmName = "itm name " + i;
            itm.ItmType = "itm type " + i;

            grp.LstItms.Add(itm);
            grp.LstItms.Add(itm);
            grp.LstItms.Add(itm);

            lst_grp.Add(grp);
        }

        this.MainGrps.Source = lst_grp;
    }
```

Is there any problem with above code?

Please help me to figure it out or suggest if you have working code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" >
```

to:

```
<GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the XAML inside the ListView tag:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Or try to set the width and the height parameter of the ListView  manually.. Just to try..

Let me know!

Comment: Sorry Its not the UI issue. It's the Collection Resource Binding issue.

Comment: Can you please try to bind the list directly to the ListView? Remove this line in code behind:

     `this.MainGrps.Source = lst_grp;`

and use this one:

    `mainListView.ItemsSource = lst_grp;`

Comment: CollectionViewSource is the means to Bind the Group of Lists. If I bind the Data directly to the ListView ItemSource, I am not able to Display the List Items within the group and I can only display headers list. But here I need to Display the list which has sublist in that. Got it?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: 

`<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainGrps}, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding GrpItmName}" `